# draw 3D solid with rectangular cell in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

How can the following figure be drawn in TikZ? It is better if the three-dimentional body is drawn with tikz-3dplot package. MWE is from [HowTo: 3D plot of a surface element with normal vector](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207468/howto-3d-plot-of-a-surface-element-with-normal-vector). Thanks for any help!
MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large]
\shadedraw[ball color=gray!40,opacity=0.5] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2,1) (-0.8,2.2) (0.5,1.3) (1,0.8) (1.8,0)
(2,-1) (1.4,-2) (0,-2.1) (-1,-1.7) (-1.8,-1)};
\draw[fill=gray!40] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (-0.3,-1.3) node[below right=0pt,
inner sep=0pt]{d$V$};
\draw[fill=gray!50] (-0.8,-0.8) -- ++ (0.2,0.2) -- ++ (0.5,0) -- (-0.3,-0.8);
\draw (-0.3,-1.3) -- ++ (0.2,0.2) -- ++ (0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `3d` library.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby,arrows.meta,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
scale=0.5,
pin distance=3cm,
every pin/.style={inner sep=1pt},
every pin edge/.style={black,very thick},
line width=2pt,
font=\Huge,
axisProp/.style={x={(-136:2cm)},
y={(-15:2cm)},
z={(90:2cm)}},
axis/.style={x={(-136:2cm)},
y={(-15:4.5cm)},
z={(90:3cm)}}]

\begin{scope}[shift={(-10,-4.7)},axisProp,>=Stealth]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
\node at (3.4,0,0) {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,13,0);
\node at (0,13.4,0) {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,9);
\node at (0,0,9.4) {$z$};
\end{scope}
\shade[ball color=green!50,closed hobby] plot coordinates 
{(15.6,-1.6) (14.2,5.4) (8.1,10.3) (1.5,11.5) (-6.2,10.7) (-12.5,7.5) (-16,1)
 (-14,-4.5) (-9,-6.5) (-5.5,-7) (-1.4,-10.3) (2.5,-12) (8,-12) (13.8,-7.4)};
\node at (-13.9,-0.3) {$D$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(1.7,0.1)},
axis]
\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,2.2) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.1cm,y radius=2.2cm] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,3.1) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.6cm,y radius=3.1cm] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,2.2) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.6cm,y radius=2.2cm] -- cycle;
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (c2) at (1,0); 
\coordinate (c3) at (1,1);
\coordinate (c4) at (0,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
\coordinate (c5) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (c6) at (1,0); 
\coordinate (c7) at (1,1);
\coordinate (c8) at (0,1);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5] 
(c1) -- (c2) -- (c6) -- (c5) -- cycle 
(c1) -- (c4) -- (c8) -- (c5) -- cycle
(c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- cycle;
\draw[red] (c1) -- (c5);
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5]
(c3) -- (c4) -- (c8) -- (c7) -- cycle
(c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- cycle;
\node[circle,
fill=blue,
minimum size=5mm,
outer sep=0pt,
pin={80:{\Huge $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$}}] at ($(c5)!0.5!(c3)$){};
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5]
(c2) -- (c3) -- (c7) -- (c6) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c2) -- (c6) (c3) -- (c7) (c8) -- (c4) -- (c3) -- (c2) (c6) -- (c7);
\begin{scope}[
every node/.style={circle,minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt},
every pin/.style={inner sep=-5pt,outer sep=0pt},
pin distance=1.35cm
]
\node[pin={300:{\Huge $\Delta x_k$}}] at ($(c3)!0.5!(c4)$){};
\node[pin={220:{\Huge $\Delta y_k$}}] at ($(c2)!0.5!(c3)$){};
\node[pin={30:{\Huge $\Delta z_k$}}] at ($(c4)!0.5!(c8)$){};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D domain]

Comment: Very nice....truly....:-) My +1.

Comment: +1 Very nicely executed!

Comment: How do you change the spot where the light reflects?

Comment: @aaragon Something can be done with `shading angle=<angle>`.

Answer (score 0):

Realized with Mathcha editor https://www.mathcha.io/editor (for new users) that export in `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_ruwzfobim/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0 bp } { 0 bp }  }  \pgftransformrotate{0 }  \pgftransformscale{2 }  }}}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{_e9u5wvow8}{150bp}{rgb(0bp)=(0.62,0.86,0.8);
rgb(37.5bp)=(0.62,0.86,0.8);
rgb(62.5bp)=(0.56,0.74,0.56);
rgb(100bp)=(0.56,0.74,0.56)}

% Gradient Info
  
\tikzset {_d5i7c38eu/.code = {\pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{ \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{89.1 bp } { -128.7 bp }  }  \pgftransformscale{1.32 }  }}}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{_ifgfxus6i}{\pgfpoint{-72bp}{104bp}}{rgb(0bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0bp)=(1,1,1);
rgb(25bp)=(0.6,0.07,0.6);
rgb(400bp)=(0.6,0.07,0.6)}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,429); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 429

%Straight Lines [id:da9703272671503154] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (100,249) -- (500.13,352.99) ;
\draw [shift={(504,354)}, rotate = 194.57] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (13.4,-6.43) -- (0,0) -- (13.4,6.44) -- (8.9,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da07813891356198277] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (100,249) -- (19.35,301.81) ;
\draw [shift={(16,304)}, rotate = 326.78] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (13.4,-6.43) -- (0,0) -- (13.4,6.44) -- (8.9,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6367469914046271] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (100,249) -- (100,38) ;
\draw [shift={(100,34)}, rotate = 450] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (13.4,-6.43) -- (0,0) -- (13.4,6.44) -- (8.9,0) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds8207629483635932] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_e9u5wvow8,_ruwzfobim] (397,66) .. controls (498,93) and (505,188) .. (505,264) .. controls (505,340) and (262,385) .. (211,312) .. controls (160,239) and (61,280) .. (41,250) .. controls (21,220) and (69,128) .. (121,82) .. controls (173,36) and (296,39) .. (397,66) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp0689038271495983] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 173; green, 223; blue, 173 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (221.31,284.27) .. controls (221.29,282.36) and (221.3,280.42) .. (221.35,278.45) .. controls (222.92,213.89) and (259.22,140.36) .. (302.77,113.02) -- (301.39,230.33) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp7558276668108921] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 173; green, 223; blue, 173 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (415.69,267.47) .. controls (410.88,204.81) and (361.53,137.63) .. (302.18,112.98) -- (301.39,230.33) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Pie [id:dp9232983870958993] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 173; green, 223; blue, 173 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (221.82,282.62) .. controls (224.13,283.37) and (226.5,284.09) .. (228.94,284.79) .. controls (292.62,303.04) and (375.21,295.15) .. (416.76,267.39) -- (301.62,230.63) -- cycle ;

%Shape: Cube [id:dp8692565257549814] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 231; green, 84; blue, 128 }  ,fill opacity=0.78 ] (280.84,214.56) -- (279.64,244.07) -- (335.22,259.86) -- (352.4,246.95) -- (353.6,217.43) -- (298.03,201.64) -- cycle ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (335.22,259.86) -- (336.42,230.35) -- (280.84,214.56) ; \draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (336.42,230.35) -- (353.6,217.43) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8370996590671183] 
\draw    (363,127) -- (314.5,235.5) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp993092194374237] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][shading=_ifgfxus6i,_d5i7c38eu] (308,235.5) .. controls (308,231.91) and (310.91,229) .. (314.5,229) .. controls (318.09,229) and (321,231.91) .. (321,235.5) .. controls (321,239.09) and (318.09,242) .. (314.5,242) .. controls (310.91,242) and (308,239.09) .. (308,235.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9856622659971559] 
\draw    (262,310) -- (303.5,250.5) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8565046745253704] 
\draw    (380,303) -- (345.5,250.5) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3030681989301671] 
\draw    (425,208) -- (353.5,234.5) ;

% Text Node
\draw (348,101.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$( x_{k} ,y_{k} ,z_{k})$};
% Text Node
\draw (426,192.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\upDelta z_{k}$};
% Text Node
\draw (241,309.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\upDelta y_{k}$};
% Text Node
\draw (365,302.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$\upDelta x_{k}$};
% Text Node
\draw (11,307.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (78,26.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$z$};
% Text Node
\draw (470,352.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\large]  {$y$};
% Text Node
\draw (100,154.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$D$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mohammadi You're welcome :-)